# i want to delete multiple photos which are selected by user

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, core-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYuDq.png)

```
 func OnDelPressed(){

    let selectedItem = self.collection.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
    print(selectedItem?.count)
    deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(selectedItem!)

}
func deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath]){
    for indexpath in indexPaths{
        //print(photos[indexpath.item])
        print("index number is: \(indexpath.row)")
        print(photos[indexpath.row])
        print("number of photos are :\(photos.count)")

        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = app.managedObjectContext

        let photo = photos[indexpath.row] as NSManagedObject
        context.deleteObject(photo)
        do{
            photos.removeAtIndex(indexpath.item)
            try context.save()

        }catch{
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print(saveError)
        }
        collection.reloadData()

    }
}
```

I can delete two photos at single time.When i select three photo it gives array index of bound error. I m out of ideas now!!

Comment: Post your code and describe more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you delete an item from your array, your index paths are no longer guaranteed to be valid.

```
for indexpath in indexPaths{
    ...
    context.deleteObject(photo)
    do {
        photos.removeAtIndex(indexpath.item)
        try context.save()
```

When you remove the photo from your array, you are changing the number of items in the array, but the index paths still refer to the items location in the array before you deleted stuff. So if your array is `[a, b, c]` and you delete item at index 0 then item at index 2, your array becomes `[b, c]` and there is no longer an item at index 2 so it crashes. If you go backwards instead (delete item at index 2 then item at index 0), it will work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of, uh, programming. When you loop to delete things by index number in programming, you need to loop *backwards from the end*. For example, if you have 4 things, delete the one at index 3, then the one at index 2, then the one at index 1, then the one at index 0.

If you don't, you'll get an out of bounds error. Think about it. Imagine we have an array of 4 items, and we loop from 0 to 3 to delete them. So:

1. We delete the one at index 0. Now everything moves down, so the array has something at index 0, 1, and 2.
2. We delete the one at index 1 (missing the one now at index 0, which is already a mistake). Now the array has something at index 0 and 1.
3. We try to delete the one at index 2 and crash, because there is no such index any longer.

Whereas, if we had simply deleted the one at index 3, then the one at index 2, then the one at index 1, then the one at index 0, everything would have been fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks . I solved this error by doing this

```
  ` func deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath]){
    var indexRef:[Int]!
    var secondIndexRef:[Int]!
    if clearImageData > 0{
        saveValue.removeAll()
    }
    for indexpath in indexPaths{
          indexRef = [indexpath.row]
            secondIndexRef = appendValue(indexRef)
    }
    secondIndexRef = secondIndexRef.sort{$0 > $1}
    print(secondIndexRef)
    for values in secondIndexRef{
        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = app.managedObjectContext
        print (values)
        let photo = photos[values] as NSManagedObject
        context.deleteObject(photo)
        do{

            photos.removeAtIndex(values)
            try context.save()
            clearImageData++

        }catch{
            let saveError = error as NSError
            print(saveError)
        }
        collection.reloadData()

    }
}
func appendValue(getValue:[Int])->[Int]{
     saveValue = saveValue + getValue
    return saveValue
}
```

`

Comment: If any of the above answers helped you get to the solution you should give them credit by marking it as accepted and/or up-voting.

Comment: Okie. i will do that